# Sequence Concatenation Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, concatenation

I have 50 lines in a txt, and the length of it is stored into a list name X. Each line has a specific length.

How should I add for it to be X0 + X0X1 + X0X1X2, and not exceed the threshold of 200? This is the best I could have done.

Let's say the list is [50,100,75,70,90,100,120..]

I want to get the output as the follows: Starting from 50: 50+100 =
150 (number of indices: 2, total value: 150, sequences are: 0,1) Then,
start with 75: 75+70 =145 (number of indices: 2, total value: 145,
sequences are: 2,3) ... ... ...

#### My Code:

```py
with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
   data = file.readlines()  # data is a list 
   #print(data)
    
data = [x.strip() for x in data] 
#print(data)

X = []

with open('output.txt','w') as fw:  #open a file to write
    count = 1
    for elem in data:
        l = len(elem)
        X.append(l) #length stored in X 
        fw.write('Starting from 50: 50+100 = 150 (number of indices: 2, total value: 150, sequences are: 0,1')
            
            
SOPP = 0
for i in X: #(should i put X here since I have inserted the length into X?)
    prod = 1
    for j in range(i+1):
        prod = prod*X[j]
    SOPP = SOPP + prod
print(SOPP)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question about the code you have shown? Is there a particular problem?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger or adding logging statements to show where your code is not behaving the way you want?

Comment: Are you trying to do it in an optimal way? If so, what is your definition of optimal? This seems to be a variation on the [line break problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_wrap_and_word_wrap)